# How to retrieve related child rows as I loop through rows from the parent table?

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, pdo

I need to run a sub-query (or something) as I iterate through the rows of an outer query. I have tried as much as I can find, but have been unable to get it to work.

Here is my while loop:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $db ORDER BY Created DESC";
$ps = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if (!$ps) {
    echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
    print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
}else{
    $ps->execute();
    $ps->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    while($row = $ps->fetch()) {

        echo "<tr>\n";

            echo "  <td>". $row->SARNo . "</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>". $row->Quals . "</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>". <!-- how do I insert results of $query here? --> . "</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>". $row->CAGE . "</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>". $row->Supplier_Name . "</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>". $row->Assigned_To_HEBCO . "</td>\n";
            echo "  <td>". $row->SAR_Completed . "</td>\n";

        echo "</tr>\n";

    }
}
```

And here is the query for getting associated NSNs for the current record:

```
$query = "SELECT NSN_Src.NSN FROM NSN_Src INNER JOIN (SAR2 INNER JOIN REL_SAR_NSN ON SAR2.ID = REL_SAR_NSN.SAR_ID) ON NSN_Src.ID = REL_SAR_NSN.NSN_ID WHERE (((SAR2.ID)=$uid))";
```

I am not very familiar with Access, and even less familiar with using Access with PHP, so this little project has been "fun" (to say the least) due to the lack of PHP functions (compared to the plethora available for MySQL).

Any help is greatly appreciated and a working solution will get you on my will for 50% of my worldly goods (which could be a lot of debt, so you can decline if you want). :)

Comment: Just a guess, but are you looking for a way to get a list of multiple NSN values as a single string like MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) would produce?

Comment: Yes, exactly like GROUP_CONCAT()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have probably discovered, Access SQL does not have an aggregate function like MySQL's [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). So, you'll need to have your PHP code create the list of child items using a second prepared statement and an inner loop, like this:

```php
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1252');
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />
<title>PDO example</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$connStr = 
        'odbc:' .
        'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};' .
        'Dbq=C:\\Users\\Public\\__SO\\28502544.mdb;' .
        'Uid=Admin;';
$db = new PDO($connStr);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sqlParent = "SELECT ID, ParentName FROM Parent";
$psParent = $db->prepare($sqlParent);

$sqlChild = "SELECT ChildName FROM Child WHERE ParentID = ?";
$psChild = $db->prepare($sqlChild);
$psChild->bindParam(1, $parentID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

echo '<table border=1>';
$psParent->execute();
while ($rowParent = $psParent->fetch()) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo $rowParent["ParentName"];
    echo '</td>';
    // collect child items into array
    $parentID = $rowParent["ID"];
    $psChild->execute();
    $childItems = array();
    while ($rowChild = $psChild->fetch()) {
        $childItems[] = $rowChild["ChildName"];
    }
    // string together and insert into table cell
    echo '<td>';
    echo implode(", ", $childItems);
    echo '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Outstanding. Thanks for your help. Been weird working with PHP and Access. Appreciate the guidance and example.